# Auth guard redirect to login after refresh

Tags: angular, angular6

Authguard redirects me to login after refresh, this is the authguard

```
constructor(private auth: AuthService,
    private router: Router) {
  }
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    if (this.auth.isLoggedIn === true) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
      return false;
    }
  }
```

This is auth service

```
  private loggedInStatus = false;
      setLoggedIn(value: boolean) {
        this.loggedInStatus = value;
      }

      get isLoggedIn() {
        return this.loggedInStatus;
      }
```

login.ts

```
  onLogin() {
    this.auth.login(this.username, this.password).subscribe(data => {
      this.auth.setLoggedIn(true);
      localStorage.setItem('login', JSON.stringify(this.auth.isLoggedIn));
      localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data));
      this.router.navigate(['']);
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
}
```

app-component.ts

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
    const login = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('login'));
    if (login !== undefined && login === true) {

      if (location.pathname === '/login') {
        this.router.navigate(['']);
        this.showMenu = false;
      } else {
        this.showMenu = true;
      }
    } else {
      if (location.pathname === '/login') {
        this.showMenu = false;
      } else {
        this.showMenu = true;
      }
    }
  }
```

`this.auth.isLoggedIn` becomes false with every refresh, I guess. I tried to read its value from localStorage, and I guess that is not the correct way to use authguard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you refresh your browser, the `AuthService` will destroy and rebuild, thus reinitializing every variable on it.

When your application starts (when you refresh) you need to check your `localStorage` to see if there's some login information and set `loggedInStatus` in `AuthService` based on this. I think you can do this on `AuthService` constructor.